# Jest : TypeError : Cannod read property 'fn' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a header component which has to be tested using jest. The header component takes in three props `setIsDark`(function), `setMode`(function), `isDark`(boolean). I thought of writing a simple test but it gives me this error : `Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`.

This is my test file **tests**/header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Header from "../header";
import jest from "jest-mock";

test("temp", () => {
  expect(true).toBe(true);
});

test("header renders some text", () => {
  const setIsDark = jest.fn();
  const setMode = jest.fn();
  const isDark = true;

  const { debug } = render(
    <Header setMode={setMode} isDark={isDark} setIsDark={setIsDark} />,
  );
  debug();
});
```

**Edit** : Without using jest mock im getting `TypeError: instace.getTotalLength is not a function`

Can somebody point out what am i doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u share your `Header` component

Answer (score 0):

Well you're importing the `jest-mock` library instead of [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest).

If you have jest installed correctly in your project you don't have to import it inside your test so if you remove
`import jest from "jest-mock";` you can use `jest.fn()` without any errors.

Comment: without jest-mock, im getting this error `TypeError: instance.getTotalLength is not a function`

Comment: Can you try importing `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`

Comment: I tried that, still getting the same error. Im using svg inside my header ..is it something related to that.

Comment: Yes, I guessed so. Your test should work otherwise

Comment: i guess jsdom doesnt support svg..so is there any workaround

Comment: I haven't come across this issue before, sorry.